# How to translate a page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome automatically translates pages not in the user's native language.

What if the browser fails to detect a foreign language? How do you manually activate the translate feature?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Translate page is reachable on
[translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/).

You may define there your languages, or use "Detect Language",
and enter the URL in the left box.
Click on the generated URL in the right box to see the translation.